# SystemOutOfMemory exception while getting the total result count in solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

I need to get the total number of solr results and save it to a variable in my model. I am using the following code for this.

SolrNet.ISolrQuery query = new SolrNet.SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(queryParts, "AND");
  model.recordsCount = solrOps.Query(query).Count;

But I am getting SystemOutOfMemory exception since the number of these solr documents is more than 17000. Is there any other way to find the total count?

p.s. I am using SolrNet 0.4.0.

Thank you

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying#Pagination https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/db271ce8b0a37f73832dda0750be6a49cfc65934/SolrNet/Impl/AbstractSolrQueryResults.cs#L7-L10

Comment: Or try asking on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet for more details.